# Python: How to convert a phylogenetic tree into a circular format?

Tags: python, biopython

I have a fasta file of aligned sequences that I want to create a phylogenetic tree for. I can create a normal branched tree like this...
[Normal branched phylogenetic tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Fed.png)

but would like to convert it so it looks something like this...[Circular phylogenetic tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCPhu.png)

The code I have used so far is below (the out_file is a filepath to the aligned fasta file)

```
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio import Phylo
from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceTreeConstructor
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

align = AlignIO.read(out_file, "fasta")
# print(align)

from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator
calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity')
dm = calculator.get_distance(align)


constructor = DistanceTreeConstructor()
tree = constructor.upgma(dm)


Phylo.draw_ascii(tree)
```

Comment: I suggest manually editing a tree file with https://icytree.org. Generally good idea to use a responsive editor for large/complicated trees.

Comment: I'm a developer of [pyCircos](https://github.com/ponnhide/pyCircos) which provides the function to draw circular phylogenetic tree visualization.  
If you are still interested in this issue, pyCircos would help to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using [ete3](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ete3 import Tree, TreeStyle
t = Tree("(((A,B),(C,D)),(E,F,G));")
circular_style = TreeStyle()
circular_style.mode = "c"
circular_style.scale = 20
t.render(figdir + "test_tree.png", w=183, units="mm", tree_style=circular_style)
```

[image]

Comment: cool any way to get rid of the blue dots ?

Comment: @pippo1980 yes, the ete3 tutorial linked in the answer contains information on modifying node style.

Comment: why circular_style = TreeStyle() instead of style = TreeStyle() given the fact that circular stile is defined afterward with circular_style.mode = "c" # c = circular

Comment: I see --> t.render(figdir + "test_tree.png", w=183, units="mm", tree_style=circular_style)